# Barcode scanning to a listbox checking for duplicates

Tags: vb.net, listbox, barcode-scanner

Good day!

I want to add some strings from a barcode scanner, captured in a text box, to a list box, and, before adding it, to check if the specific string hasn't been already added. So I have a text box called txtWO which captures what the reader scans and a list box called lstScanBOM to which I add the text box string if the item is not already added. The problem is, that whatever I do, only after the specific string is added twice the checking for duplicate entry starts to work. In other words I scan the same string twice, it added it, and then when I scan the third time only it throws the message with the error saying it is a duplicate. I don't understand why is doing this. The code is below:
[image]

```
Private Sub frmValidareFIP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If txtWO.Focused = False Then
        txtWO.Select()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddUnique(StringToAdd As String)
    If lstScanBom.Items.Contains(StringToAdd) = True Then
        MsgBox("Articol duplicat!", vbOKOnly)
    Else
        'it does not exist, so add it..
        lstScanBom.Items.Add(StringToAdd)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtWO_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtWO.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim barcode As String
        barcode = txtWO.Text
        AddUnique(barcode)
        txtWO.Clear()
        txtWO.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use a hash set list, that way it will never add it in the first place if it’s a duplicate

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

IMO Try listing the data outside of the ListBox. I can't see why it isn't working, maybe we need a third pair of eyes to see it!?

Try adding a list (of string) as a Private within the form, populate this as your user scans, and check the duplicate there..

This is definately not the best solution, but I'm sure it will help!

```
Private List_Barcodes As List(Of String)
Private Sub frmValidareFIP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    List_Barcodes = New List(Of String)
    'You can also populate this list on load, if you have a stored cahce of previous scanned barcodes?
    'List_Barcodes.Add("0123456")
    'List_Barcodes.Add("4567890")
    '...etc

    If txtWO.Focused = False Then
        txtWO.Select()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddUnique(StringToAdd As String)
    If List_Barcodes.Contains(StringToAdd) Then
        MsgBox("Articol duplicat!", vbOKOnly)
    Else
        'Place into dynamic list
        List_Barcodes.Add(StringToAdd)
        'and Place into your listbox
        lstScanBom.Items.Add(StringToAdd)
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub txtWO_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtWO.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim barcode As String
        barcode = txtWO.Text
        AddUnique(barcode)
        txtWO.Clear()
        txtWO.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your barcode reader is returning <carriage return><line feed> as enter.  Your code catches the enter key (carriage return = 13), but leaves the line feed (10) character.  So the next time you scan something it will start with a line feed.  The two strings in your example are different because the first is "58335001" and the second is "<line feed>58335001".  The third one is "<line feed>58335001", which is a duplicate of the second.

One way to fix this is to trim your string.

```
Private Sub txtWO_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtWO.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim barcode As String
        'Add the .Trim() to remove the leading <line feed> character
        barcode = txtWO.Text.Trim()
        AddUnique(barcode)
        txtWO.Clear()
        txtWO.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple decision is ONLY to make your textBox control txtWO NOT multiline 
And that's enough! Your code will work correctly!